# Creating Public Routes

Tags: reactjs, routes, jhipster, private, public

I'm trying to create a public route for an entity that I created in JHipster. The entity is a Create API call for a form - name, email, phone number, etc. - that I'm allowing people to fill out for public submission.

JHipster made the entity for the the Admin and User portals. So I'm able to submit/create a new form there; however, I'm wanting to make the same thing available for those who are not signed in as a User or Admin.

My first thought was to create a new public route(s) that would navigate to a new copy/past of the form in a new/separate component file. But I couldn't help but shake that there is another way? Possibly, by adding "public" somewhere for this specific create API call?

What would be my best path to make this entity public and private for both people viewing the website and also for Users/Admins?

Thank you for your time!

---

UPDATE:

Upon looking at it there is an axios interceptor that is checking to see if if they are authorized or unauthorized, and this is what is allowing something to be private or public.

So, the question changes: how would we update this interceptor to have some API calls "public" and some "private"? Should it be an if/else or should we simply create a new API call to the same entity that is public from the backend and channel that to the frontend as a new API call?

For example: we would like for people to view the blogs in a public view, but we would not want people who are not logged in/unauthorized to create, update, or delete blogs.

Comment: I just created an angular app, but maybe that helps too. I would suggest to make an additional public api path which has permitAll in the spring security configuration. When it comes to the frontend part (just tried angular) I would also suggest to separate the public part from the default crud part. With this you e.g. could use different dto projections for the public and default part.